# Как посчитать разницу между датами в днях?

Tags: php, mysql

у меня есть три таблицы:

в одной `data1_start`(varchar) дата начала,

в другой  `data2_end`(varchar) дата конца,

в третьей `status`(varchar) статус оповещения.

Мне надо отнять текущую дату от `data1_start`. Если останется 20 дней и больше до `data2_end`, в третью таблицу в поле `status` записать какое-то число

Comment: ничо не понял) наверна я не одинок))

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php Вам в помощь. Получаете из таблицы даты. Используете встроенную функцию. Проверяете её на 20 дней, выполняете дальнейшее действие.

Comment: Фраза некорректно построена: "Если останется 20 дней и больше до data2_end". Если останется 20 дней **от чего**?

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, даты в формате MySql. Тогда

```
$day = 24 * 60 * 60; // Длина одного дня в секундах

$data1_start = ['2017-10-01', '2017-10-02']
$data2_end = ['2017-10-10', '2017-10-12']

$current = strtotime('now');
foreach($data1_start as $k => $v){
    $start = strtotime($data1_start[$k]);
    $end = strtotime($data2_end[$k]);
    // Оповещение за 20 дней до начала
    // Т.е. осталось меньше 20 дней
    if($start - $current < 20 * $day){
        $status[$k] = 43;
    }
}
```

Comment: а что это за переменная $x?

Comment: Я предположил, что есть какая-то запись из таблицы. Назвал её $x. В ней поля $x['data1_start'] и $x['data2_end'].

Comment: Таблица типа varchar быть не может. Это поле в таблице должно быть.

Comment: в таблице ['data1_start'] вложена дата Y-m-d и также в таблице ['data2_end'] вложена дата Y-m-d

Comment: "В таблице" - в смысле "в массиве"?

Comment: Если "отнять текущую дату от " другой даты, получим период (5 дней, например). Как от периода может остаться 20 дней до  data2_end?

Comment: Что за олдскульные умножения для вычисления "дней в секундах"? Как говорил один препод "чтобы это сделать - для этого надо подумать. а мне голова не для этого нужна!". Используйте DateTime, в самом деле - там человекопонятные конструкции, памяти занимает не намного больше (реально мизерная разница), при этом оно работает в большей части случаев быстрее в разы.